# Initial screen just went wordless

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

[image][image: screen went wordless]
[image]
There's no lock in the one that seems to be causing the problem. Is there a way to "factory reset the game"? It is an XBox One S

I'm just a mom with no idea how to fix this for my boys. I did restart it, that didn't work. I tried changing packs - best I could without words, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Did you try to restart it? Also does clicking on them make words appear on the next screen? Also have you installed any mods or texture packs resource packs?

Comment: yes, did restart it, that didn't work. I tried changing packs -best I could without words, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Is this the Java Edition, or one of the Bedrock Editions (any of the consoles, Android, IOS, or the Windows 10 Edition)?  It looks to me like one of the Bedrock Edition loading screens.

Comment: This does look like Xbox Windows 10 Edition. My game bugs out if I need to update so I'd check for updates.

Comment: It is Xbox One S

Comment: The default texture pack is causing the problem.  The most likely place to fix this would be in the XBox Marketplace page for the game.  You should be able to perform an update from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly a texture resource pack.  They're capable of changing how the loading screen is displayed.  Click on the third button.  This will bring you to the settings screen:

[image: Minecraft BE settings]

In the General (last) section, the fourth option (at least for me) is Global Resources:

[image]

Notice how the Minecraft Texture Pack doesn't have a lock icon on it.  Also nothing happens when you click it.  You want to disable all other texture packs in the Active Packs section.  Do this by clicking on them, then clicking on the <kbd>-</kbd> button (which is the left of 4 buttons appearing under the resource pack info).  This doesn't delete them, just disables them.  After that, it should be back to normal.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, you can show others that by clicking the check mark.  Upvoting the answer also helps.

Comment: Ok.. How do I add a picture again here? It didn't solve it..

Comment: You can edit your question, and in the edit dialog, you'll see a button for uploading images.  Then you can just drag and drop from the folder the picture is in, and the system will do most of the work for you.  Since this answer didn't work for you, I'd suggest looking into the suggestion @Robbie made in his comment and try updating the game.  I, unfortunately, don't have a good set of steps for doing that.